# Casos de uso - ¿Puede un actor tener un rol?

Tags: uml

Soy muy nuevo en programación y UML, así que tengo esta duda:
Tengo un requerimiento que especifica que todo aquel que use el sistema se le denomina "usuario", y los únicos que pueden usar el sistema son "empleados", así que todo usuario es un empleado.
Cada usuario debe tener un rol, y entre estos están el rol de "Administrador" y "Jefe".
Tambien existe un cliente, y este puede realizar peticiones al sistema, las cuales pueden ser aceptadas o rechazadas por el Jefe, pero como el Administrador tambien tiene acceso total al sistema, este tambien puede hacerlo.
Mi duda es que, en UML, **¿es posible especificar que un actor tiene un rol?**
**¿Puedo colocar dos actores "Usuario" y especificar de alguna forma que uno tiene el rol de "Administrador" y el otro el de "Jefe"?**
Lo que quisiera hacer es algo como en la imagen que se ve a continuación:
[image: Caso de uso en donde se muestran tres actores. Dos de ellos son usuarios y uno de ellos es un cliente. Los usuarios se llaman "Usuario (Administrador)" y "Usuario (Jefe)"]

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Generalmente, en los diagramas de caso de uso, los actores se clasifican por sus roles así que sí puedes tener un actor Administrador y otro actor Jefe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generalmente, en los diagramas de caso de uso, los actores se clasifican por sus roles así que sí puedes tener un actor Administrador y otro actor Jefe.
Aún así, si necesitas especificar el actor usuario, puedes hacer una **relación de generalización** ente ellos, algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Cabe destacar que es poco común por no decir que es una mala práctica el colocar actores que no ejercen ninguna acción importante en el diagrama porque puede crear confusión en comprender los diferentes puntos de inicio el mismo.

En la mayoría de los casos se puede sustituir el actor final con una descripción de la acción. Por ejemplo: en el paso final de la entrega de un paquete no pondrías una flecha indicando un actor "cliente" sino más bien una flecha hacia una acción denominada "entrega del paquete" dado que el rol del actor "cliente" queda implícito en dicha acción y el nombre de esta es más auto explicativo.